# JS how to insert a picture of a certain duration into a video fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to insert a picture into a video to make the video longer, I use fluent-ffmpeg for this.
I have the life span of the picture and the path to the video. For example, I want to insert a video image at 5 seconds. The picture will play for 5 seconds and then the video will continue.